# Designing cube in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

When I rotate the cube, 2 Sides of cubes are opaque while others are transparent.

**Output:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Cube',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const Cube(),
    );
  }
}
class Cube extends StatefulWidget {
  const Cube({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CubeState createState() => _CubeState();
}
class _CubeState extends State<Cube> {
  Offset offset = Offset.zero;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Cube"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            print(details);
            setState(() {
              offset += details.delta;
            });
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.identity()
                ..rotateX(-offset.dy * pi / 180)
                ..rotateY(-offset.dx * pi / 180),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.identity()..translate(0.0, 0.0, -100),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        child: const FlutterLogo(
                          size: 200,
                        ),
                      )),
                  Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.identity()
                        ..translate(-100.0, 0.0, 0.0)
                        ..rotateY(-pi / 2),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: const FlutterLogo(
                          size: 200,
                        ),
                      )),
                  Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.identity()..translate(0.0, 0.0, 100.0),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: const FlutterLogo(
                          size: 200,
                        ),
                      )),
                  Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.identity()
                        ..translate(100.0, 0.0, 0.0)
                        ..rotateY(-pi / 2),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.purple,
                        child: const FlutterLogo(
                          size: 200,
                        ),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I used the code from a tutorial from Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDmWOsOU_Ko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flutter will always render the children of the Stack in order, what means that the last widget of the Stack will be in front of every other widget, and that is why the purple side (the last child of the Stack) is always visible regardless of the movement you do.

To simulate a cube you will have to change the order of the cube's sides accordingly to the rotation of the cube. To change the order, you will have to store all the sides in an array and pass this array as the argument of the Stack:

```dart
class _CubeState extends State<Cube> {
  List<Widget> sides = [];
  
  final side1 = Transform(
    key: const ValueKey("side1"), // you must use a key to allow flutter to know that a widget changed its order
    transform: Matrix4.identity()..translate(0.0, 0.0, -100),
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: const FlutterLogo(size: 200),
    ),
  );
  //... the other sides follow the same logic of the side1


  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    sides = [side1, side2, side3, side4];
  }

  void update(Offset value) {
    setState(() {
      // I recommend to normalize the offset to be always between [0, 360) 
      offset = Offset((offset.dx + value.dx) % 360, (offset.dy + value.dy) % 360);
      sides = [side1, side3, ...] // change the order of the sides here accordingly with the new offset value. This is the hardest part. For a cube where you want to render all the 6 sides, you will have to perform a lot of calculations to know which side is in front of which.
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // The rendered cube is inside the `Center` widget below
          Center(
            child: Transform(
              key: const ValueKey('cube'),
              transform: Matrix4.identity()
                ..rotateX(-offset.dy * pi / 180)
                ..rotateY(-offset.dx * pi / 180),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Stack(
                children: sides,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // The gesture recognizer that will receive the movement of the mouse is inside the `Positioned.fill`
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onPanUpdate: (details) {
                      update(details.delta);
                    },
                    child: Container(color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                ),
                Text('x: ${offset.dx} y: ${offset.dy}')
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Note that you need to pass an unique key to every widget in the Stack to make it possible to Flutter identify uniquely every widget (you can see more about Keys in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc).

I made a simple example below with a cube of 4 sides. To do the same in a cube of 6 sides will require more math, but I think I gave you enough knowledge to you figure it out that by yourself.

https://dartpad.dev/?id=3698b3013fe7189d3c3c063d088cf69a

#### How to capture the mouse movement independently of how the cube is rotated/transformed.

If the `GestureRecognizer` has the transformed cube as its child, the movement of the mouse will capture the original cube's side that was being show at the beggining (the blue side in my example), thus depending on how the cube is rotated, if the blue side is not visible anymore, the mouse will not be captured anymore. To solve that we have to split the mouse capture logic of the cube's rendering.

There are many possible ways, one of those is to render a `Stack` (to make one child be in front of another child, creating multiple layers). The underlayer will be used to render the cube and the overlayer will be used to capture the mouse movement (this layer needs to be transparent to don't affect the visualization of the cube).

I did that with the cobe below:

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Center( // This is the underlayer that renders the cube. It will be always in the center of the screen.
      child: Transform(
        key: const ValueKey('cube'),
        transform: Matrix4.identity()
          ..rotateX(-offset.dy * pi / 180)
          ..rotateY(-offset.dx * pi / 180),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Stack(
          children: sides,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned.fill( // This is the overlayer that receives the mouse/finger movement. It has to be a `Positioned.fill` if you want that all the available space can be used to rotate the cube.
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          update(details.delta);
        },
        child: Container(color: Colors.transparent), // We need any widget that actually renders pixels on the screen and that can have a size. If not, the `GestureRecognizer` would have size zero and would not work. The colors is transparent to allow the cube (that it is in the underlayer) to be visible.
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: This code is facing a problem. When I rotate and release the cube with purple or red face exactly in front, Gesture detector does not work hence cube does not move. Please help me to fix this since you have a better understanding of your code.

Comment: I updated the answer and the code example to fix this issue. Basically, you have to split the cube's render logic from the mouse capture.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below code. :)

[image]

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: CreateApp(),
        ),
      ),
    );

num map(num value,
        [num iStart = 0, num iEnd = pi * 2, num oStart = 0, num oEnd = 1.0]) =>
    ((oEnd - oStart) / (iEnd - iStart)) * (value - iStart) + oStart;

class CreateApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateApp({super.key});

  @override
  CreateAppState createState() => CreateAppState();
}

class CreateAppState extends State<CreateApp> {
  final List<Widget> _list = <Widget>[];
  final double _size = 140.0;

  double _x = pi * 0.25, _y = pi * 0.25;
  late Timer _timer;

  int get size => _list.length;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      // Rainbow
      LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (_, BoxConstraints c) => Stack(
                  children: _list.map((Widget w) {
                final num i = map(size - _list.indexOf(w), 0, 150);

                return Positioned(
                    top: (c.maxHeight / 2 - _size / 2) + i * c.maxHeight * 0.9,
                    left: (c.maxWidth / 2 - _size / 2) - i * c.maxWidth * 0.9,
                    child: Transform.scale(scale: i * 1.5 + 1.0, child: w));
              }).toList())),

      // Cube
      GestureDetector(
          onDoubleTap: _start,
          onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails u) => setState(() {
                _x = (_x + -u.delta.dy / 150) % (pi * 2);
                _y = (_y + -u.delta.dx / 150) % (pi * 2);
              }),
          child: Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Cube(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade200, x: _x, y: _y, size: _size))),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _start() {
    if (_timer.isActive) {
      return;
    }

    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 48), (_) => _add());
  }

  void _add() {
    if (size > 150) {
      _list.removeRange(0, Colors.accents.length * 4);
    } // Expensive, remove more at once

    setState(() => _list.add(Cube(
        x: _x,
        y: _y,
        color: Colors.accents[_timer.tick % Colors.accents.length]
            .withOpacity(0.2),
        rainbow: true,
        size: _size)));
  }
}

class Cube extends StatelessWidget {
  const Cube(
      {super.key,
      required this.x,
      required this.y,
      required this.color,
      required this.size,
      this.rainbow = false});

  static const double _shadow = 0.2, _halfPi = pi / 2, _oneHalfPi = pi + pi / 2;

  final double x, y, size;
  final Color color;
  final bool rainbow;

  double get _sum => (y + (x > pi ? pi : 0.0)).abs() % (pi * 2);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool topBottom = x < _halfPi || x > _oneHalfPi;
    final bool northSouth = _sum < _halfPi || _sum > _oneHalfPi;
    final bool eastWest = _sum < pi;

    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      _side(
          zRot: y,
          xRot: -x,
          shadow: _getShadow(x).toDouble(),
          moveZ: topBottom),
      _side(
          yRot: y,
          xRot: _halfPi - x,
          shadow: _getShadow(_sum).toDouble(),
          moveZ: northSouth),
      _side(
          yRot: -_halfPi + y,
          xRot: _halfPi - x,
          shadow: _shadow - _getShadow(_sum),
          moveZ: eastWest)
    ]);
  }

  num _getShadow(double r) {
    if (r < _halfPi) {
      return map(r, 0, _halfPi, 0, _shadow);
    } else if (r > _oneHalfPi) {
      return _shadow - map(r, _oneHalfPi, pi * 2, 0, _shadow);
    } else if (r < pi) {
      return _shadow - map(r, _halfPi, pi, 0, _shadow);
    }

    return map(r, pi, _oneHalfPi, 0, _shadow);
  }

  Widget _side(
      {bool moveZ = true,
      double xRot = 0.0,
      double yRot = 0.0,
      double zRot = 0.0,
      double shadow = 0.0}) {
    return Transform(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      transform: Matrix4.identity()
        ..rotateX(xRot)
        ..rotateY(yRot)
        ..rotateZ(zRot)
        ..translate(0.0, 0.0, moveZ ? -size / 2 : size / 2),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: size, height: size),
          color: color,
          foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(rainbow ? 0.0 : shadow),
            border: Border.all(
              width: 0.8,
              color: rainbow ? color.withOpacity(0.3) : Colors.black26,
            ),
          ),
          child: const FlutterLogo(
            size: 200,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Singh saab, I have upvoted your answer but bounty is earned by Eduardo Vital. He posted a answer before you.

Comment: Answers should have explanations, not just code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290231/is-it-wrong-to-ask-for-an-explanation-of-how-why-the-code-works-in-code-only-ans

Comment: @satvikpendem next time i will keep in mind :) thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @HarsimranSingh add an explanation now at least